# Stationary and Extreme points

Tags: calculus

If we have a function $y = 2x^2$, where $0\le x\le 1$, where are the stationary points? There is one when $x = 0$, but are the endpoints also considered stationary points when they are inclusive?

Additionally if we have a function $y = x^\frac{1}{2}$, where is the extrema? Is there an extrema at the endpoint where $x = 0$?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The endpoints are not automatically considered stationary - stationary points are just defined as solutions to the equation $x=f(x)$, so in the first case we have
$$x=2x^2\hspace{5mm}\implies\hspace{5mm}2x^2-x=0\hspace{5mm}\implies\hspace{5mm} x(2x-1)=0$$
so $x=0$ and $x=\dfrac{1}{2}$ are the stationary points (note that both $0$ and $\dfrac12$ are in the domain). In particular notice that the endpoint $1$ is not a stationary point, so the endpoints don't have to be stationary.

Your second question appears quite different in nature, but I can answer it anyway. Note first that $\sqrt{x}$ is only defined on the interval $[0,\infty)$. Now in order to find the extremum, we can take the derivative and set it equal to $0$, and compare the values at those solutions to the values at the boundary:
$$0=\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{x}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$$
but this has no solutions for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ (because we need $|x|=\infty$ to make the right-hand side $0$). Hence the only exremum if any come at the boundary. Noting that $\sqrt{0}=0$ and $\sqrt{x}>0$ if $x>0$, we find that the function is minimized at $0$. Since $0$ is the only real boundary point, we have found the only extremum of this function.